# Помогите сделать подобный зум

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, как сделать подобное на js? Есть картинка по наведению на которую появляется окно в увеличенным изображением. Эдакий эффект лупы. Кроме стандартного плагина на jquery ничего не могу найти(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Где-то такое решение я уже видел:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var zoomMargin = 15;

  function startZoom(e) {
    $('.zoomer .large').css('left', $(this).width() + zoomMargin).show(); // Контейнер у большим изображением становится видимым.
  }

  function moveZoom(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset(), // В переменной offset хранятся координаты блока с миниатюрой
      x = (e.pageX - offset.left), // В переменной хранится координата X курсора мыши относительно блока с миниатюрой
      y = (e.pageY - offset.top); // Координата Y курсора мыши.
    w = $(this).width(), // Ширина миниатюры
      h = $(this).height(), // Высота миниатюры
      // Позиционирование фона большого изображения относительно того, куда указывает курсор на миниатюре.
      $('.large').css({
        'background-position': (x / w * 100) + '% ' + (y / h * 100) + '%'
      });
  }

  function endZoom(e) {
    $('.zoomer .large').hide(); // Контейнер с большим изображением скрывается
  }
  $('.small').on({
    'mouseenter': startZoom, // При наведении мыши на миниатюру срабатывает функция startZoom
    'mousemove': moveZoom, // Когда курсор мыши перемещается внутри миниатюры срабатывает функция moveZoom
    'mouseleave': endZoom // Когда мышь уходит из области миниатюры срабатывает функция endZoom
  });
})
```

```css
.zoomer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.zoomer .small {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://kalushnews.city/upload/test_img/2266/questions/o_1djrf1fdu1mcmvm6ha51qv2vdjel.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока. */
  position: absolute;
}

.zoomer .large {
  background: url(https://kalushnews.city/upload/test_img/2266/questions/o_1djrf1fdu1mcmvm6ha51qv2vdjel.jpg) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoomer">
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Получилось что-то такое:

```js
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let isImg = e.target.nodeName === "IMG";
  if (isImg) {
    let r = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    frame.style.top =  e.y - 50 + "px";
    frame.style.left = e.x - 50 + "px";
    preview.style.background = `url(https://picsum.photos/id/85/900/900) no-repeat`;
    preview.style.backgroundPosition = `${150-(e.x-r.x)*3}px ${150-(e.y-r.y)*3}px`
  } 
  preview.style.display = frame.style.display = isImg ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
})
```

```css
#frame {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #0002;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

#preview {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/85/300/300" />
<div id="preview"></div>
<div id="frame"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеку https://github.com/malaman/js-image-zoom

Пример: http://malaman.github.io/js-image-zoom/example/